# How can I force ProgressView to run its task again?

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper

I have content that is loaded in the background.
Loading is a long running task and I want to show data as soon as it's available.
My view show loaded content and a `ProgressView` whenever there is more content to be expected.

```
struct MyListView : View
{
  @MyContent
  var content: [MyItem]

  var body: some View
  {
    List
    {
      //...show content elements
      if content.hasMoreData()
      {
         ProgressView().task
         {
            await _content.load(.end)
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use a custom `propertyWrapper` to load the data.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyContent<E> : DynamicProperty
{
  final class Container<E> : ObservableObject
  {
    var wrappedValue : [E]
  }
  
  let container: Container<E>
  var wrappedValue : [E] { container.wrappedValue }
 
  func load() async
  {
     //...load more content
  }
}
```

When the view loads, the `ProgressView` spins and the `load` function is called.
After more data has been loaded the view is refreshed. Unfortunately however the task on the `ProgressView` is not renewed. The `load` function is not called again.

I also tried wrapping the `MyContent` wrapper in an `ObservableObject` but with similar effects.

```
final class MyBox<E> : ObservableObject
{
  @MyContent
  var content: [MyItem]

  func load() async
  {
    await _content.load(position)
    await send()
  }

  @MainActor
  private func send() async
  {
    objectWillChange.send()
  }
}
```

If I look at `FetchRequest` which is a `struct` and which has a `batchLimit`, I think it should not be necessary to use `MyBox` or an `ObservableObject' just to trigger and additional` load` call.

How can I force the `ProgressView` to run the task again?

Comment: What if you assign a new `id` to the `ProgressView`/`task`?

Comment: You like need a `AsyncStream`

Comment: Maybe? I only want to load elements when the user scrolls up or down to see them. So lazily load them when they should be displayed. In the mean time show a spinner but also add elements as soon as they are available.